# Displaying all search results in Python web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am quite new to Python and am building a web scraper, which will scrape the following page and links in them: https://www.nalpcanada.com/Page.cfm?PageID=33

The problem is the page's default is to display the first 10 search results, however, I want to scrape all 150 search results (when 'All' is selected, there are 150 links).

I have tried messing around with the URL, but the URL remains static no matter what display results option is selected. I have also tried to look at the Network section of the Developer Tools on Chrome, but can't seem to figure out what to use to display all results.

Here is my code so far:

```
import bs4
import requests
import csv
import re

response = requests.get('https://www.nalpcanada.com/Page.cfm?PageID=33')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
urls = []

for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True, class_="employerProfileLink", text="Vancouver, British Columbia"):
    urls.append(a['href'])

pagesToCrawl = ['https://www.nalpcanada.com/' + url + '&QuestionTabID=47' for url in urls]

for pages in pagesToCrawl:
    html = requests.get(pages)
    soupObjs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")

    nameOfFirm = soupObjs.find('div', class_="ip-left").find('h2').next_element

    tbody = soupObjs.find('div', {"id":"collapse8"}).find('tbody')
    offers = tbody.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_element
    seeking = tbody.find('tr').next_sibling.next_sibling.find('td').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_element

    print('Firm name:', nameOfFirm)
    print('Offers:', offers)
    print('Seeking:', seeking)
    print('Hireback Rate:', int(offers) / int(seeking))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing your `response` call with this code seems to work. The reason is that you weren't passing in the cookie properly.

```
response = requests.get(
    'https://www.nalpcanada.com/Page.cfm',
    params={'PageID': 33},
    cookies={'DISPLAYNUM': '100000000'}
)
```

The only other issue I came across was that a `ValueError` was being raised by this line when certain links (like `YLaw Group`) don't seem to have "offers" and/or "seeking".

```
print('Hireback Rate:', int(offers) / int(seeking))
```

I just commented out the line since you will have to decide what to do in those cases.

Comment: @Fitzy Glad to help!